# Gstreamer compositor using filesrc mp4 file

Tags: gstreamer, mp4

I'm trying to get used to using the gstreamer compositor.
I have this basic boilerplate example working. (Compositing 2 videotestsrc next to each other):

```
gst-launch-1.0 compositor name=comp \
    sink_0::alpha=1 sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 \
    sink_1::alpha=0.5 sink_1::xpos=320 sink_1::ypos=0 ! \
    queue2 ! video/x-raw, width=800, height=600 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink \
    videotestsrc pattern=1 ! "video/x-raw" ! comp.sink_0 \
    videotestsrc pattern=8 ! "video/x-raw" ! comp.sink_1
```

Then I tried changing one of the video test src to a mp4 file
I know that this command line works:
`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=tst.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

So I tried combining these two working pipelines

```
gst-launch-1.0 compositor name=comp \
    sink_0::alpha=1 sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 \
    sink_1::alpha=0.5 sink_1::xpos=320 sink_1::ypos=0 ! \
    queue2 ! decodebin ! video/x-raw, width=800, height=600 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink \
    videotestsrc pattern=1 ! "video/x-raw" ! comp.sink_0 \
    filesrc location=tst.mp4 ! "video/x-raw" ! comp.sink_1
```

When I run this I get an error saying that the filter caps do not complete specify the output format.... output caps are unfixed.

I'm positive this must be a simple syntax error.  Does anyone know how to fix my pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to use most of the elements that made the standalone command line work. E.g.

```
gst-launch-1.0 compositor name=comp \
    sink_0::alpha=1 sink_0::xpos=0 sink_0::ypos=0 \
    sink_1::alpha=0.5 sink_1::xpos=320 sink_1::ypos=0 ! \
    queue2 ! decodebin ! video/x-raw, width=800, height=600 ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink \
    videotestsrc pattern=1 ! "video/x-raw" ! comp.sink_0 \
    filesrc location=tst.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! comp.sink_1
```

Comment: Hi Florian, thanks for your suggestion. Was the pipeline you posted supposed to run as is?
I tried your example as is and I get this warning: "capsfilter2: not negotiated."
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstDecodeBin:decodebin1/GstQTDemux:qtdemux0: Internal data stream error.

Comment: Depends on what codec is inside the .mp4 and if you have decoders for it.